# Flask form.populate_obj() keep null values

Tags: python, flask

I have an edit function where I edit certain data. The form (I use flask_wtf) is the same, so I can use:

```
form.populate_obj(build)
```

Now I see all old values and can edit them, but some fields do not have a value. These fields are `null` in the DB. Often I dont need to edit them so I simply ignore them.

And here is the problem, if I submit the edit form all values which should remain `null` become an empty string `""`

Here is a precise example:

Thats an entry where I want only to edit `date_added`. I ignore `bandits` and `additional_info`.
[image]

After submit I expect that `bandits` and `additional_info` still are `null`, but they change:

[image]

Of course I could rewrite the whole code and use the same logic where I add these values to the DB, but I feel like there should be a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you add filters to your form fields:

```
filters = [lambda x: x or None]
```

For example like this:

```
birthtown = StringField("Birthtown", filters = [lambda x: x or None])
```

This will either use whatever you write in the field or None. At least you will get rid of the empty strings. Or is this too much rewriting to be acceptable?

Comment: Great solution, I haven't thought about filters. Thanks